# How to avoid romancing jack but not making her mad? (Plus Tali and Liara)

Tags: ps3, mass-effect-2, mass-effect-series

I've manage to avoid Miranda romance now she replies with the neutral response of shes got work to do and avoiding going on the left of Kellys' speech options. I like talking to the crew(and getting those paragon points) but now after her loyalty mission she asked if I have feelings for her. How do I tell her no without her getting frustrated and telling you not to talk to her anymore, or becoming disappointed and not wanting you to come around for awhile? The same goes for tali, how do I go about paragon choices without romancing tali accidentally? Doing the shadow broker and not having a romance situation with liara I've heard about?

Comment: The title is about Jack, but she isn't mentioned anywhere in the question.  Is there a character that you're specifically worried about, or all options in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really have to be quite deliberate in order to romance someone.  Even if you lead someone on, you're not going to break their heart when the obvious "let's have sex" conversation pops up and you say no; people in the Mass Effect universe take rejection surprisingly well.  Chalk it up to a "(S)He's just trying to save the galaxy, and doesn't have time for romance" mentality your crew seems to have.

What you experienced was the end of the dialog tree prior to her loyalty mission.  More options become available as the story progresses.  It shouldn't be taken to mean that you've pissed them off (although with Miranda in particular, it sure comes off that way).

In the end, paragon and renegade options typically only add a little to romance options.  It shouldn't be something to be worried about.